# How to create a mongo db using javascript ?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sails.js

I am trying to create a mongodb on the fly based on user input using javascript.  Here is a snipit of the code I am writing.

```
mp.MongoClient.connect("mongodb://admin:admin_password@mongo_server.com:27017/admin")
              .then(function (db) {
                 getListOfDatabases(db)
        .then(function (databases) {
            if (doesDatabaseExist(databases)) {
                mp.MongoClient.connect("mongodb://admin:admin_password@mongo_server.com:27017/"+userDefinedDb)
                    .then(function (userDb) {
                        insertInFakeCollection(userDb, dbObject);
                        createRead(userDb, dbObject);
                    })
                    .fail(function(err){
                        console.log(err);
                    })
            }
        })
})
.fail(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
})
```

I am able to to connect and get a list of databases, I try to connect to the user defined database, mongo throws me an error { [MongoError: auth failed] name: 'MongoError', ok: 0,errmsg: 'auth failed', code: 18 }

The admin password and user name are the same and it has role userAdminAnyDatabase.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong or why this issue is occurring.  any help is appreciated.

Comment: For read/write access, you need the `read`/`readWrite` permission.

Comment: Aside from the errors, what is your percieved purpose here? MongoDB will create database containers and collections "on the fly" anyway as soon as you reference the namespace. So there is no need to go and create either in a separate process, as any other code you have that uses the required namespace will just create the required objects anyway.

Comment: the purpose is to allow users to create a mongodb.  I have server in which people can create and delete their own mongodbs.  So when a user comes in ask for a mongodb they give me a name they want to call it and through code i create it.  The fake collection is generated because I believe that in order for the database to actually exist it needs a collection.